# Not working ng-click in angular.js, why i undestand not

Tags: angularjs

I make insert in tag ng-controller in button. I know not right maked i.

this is controller

```
handler.controller('Handler',['$scope','$http', function ($scope, 
$http) {

$scope.delIp = function (id) {
    
 $http.post('mysite',id).then(function(response){
   if(response.data.res == true){
 console.log("deleted successfully");
     }  
    });
  }
}]);
```

html

```
 <div class="block">

             <label>IP</label> 

         <select ng-options="ips.id as ips.ip for ips in ip track by ip.id"
                ng-model="selectedIp">

    </select>           
   <button  ng-click="delIp(selectedIp)">-</button>
         </div>
```

if click on button minus, i get in console message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres 2 things wrong here

1. you have a typo, ng-click="delIP" (should match case of your javascript)
2. you dont need to put the ng-controller on each html block... Each segement should be encapsulated inside the relevant controller. Read more documentation\examples on controllers

Comment: I found errors and fixed them in the problem description